# Bar graph not showing both $ and % columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to display both the $ and the % on a column or bar chart. On Google Sheets, the % isn't showing at all only the $. How do I get a side by side column showing both the $ and %? Here is the link to my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r4bmO4qkalgTusk2m_iKcKd87EtyQXJSEwO-7MYkCao/edit?usp=sharing [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Settings, change the chart type to be comb chart
2. In Customize -> Series, change the axis of `Share` series to be right
3. In Customize -> Y-axis, change the display format to currency

[image]

Comment: This is perfect thank you. Could you explain why it needed to be like this in order for it to show?